# Correct Way To Use CSP Filter In Play 2.7

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to define the CSP policy for my web service and am using the new features in [Scala Play 2.7](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/CspFilter).

This is what I have done:

1. Set the CSP directive and nonce configuration in my application.conf

```
      csp {
        nonce {
          enabled = true
          pattern = "%CSP_NONCE_PATTERN%"
          header = false
        }

        directives {
          base-uri = "'none'"
          object-src = "'none'"
          script-src = ${play.filters.csp.nonce.pattern} "'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:"
        }
      }
```

2. In the Twirl template I make reference to the nonce as follows:

```scala
<script @{CSPNonce.attr}...</script>

<script @{CSPNonce.attr} ..</script>
```

A couple of observations:

1. According to the documentation, if I switch on `csp.header = true` in the application.conf, I should see the nonce value in the RequestHeader which is implicitly brought into the Twirl template. I don't see this header at all when I print out the the header values.
2. Similarly, I don't see the nonce value in the script tags when I view the generated HTML in my browser.
3. Irrespective of whether I add the `@{CSPNonce.attr}` Twirl snippet in my inline script code, the inline JS gets loaded. This is strange as I thought only inline scripts marked with the correct nonce would only be allowed to load.

So what is the deal here? Am I not using this feature correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have not enabled the filter.

Please check that you have added

```
play.filters.enabled += play.filters.csp.CSPFilter
```

to your `application.conf`.

You're also using `csp` instead of `play.filters.csp` in your configuration example, so that could be an issue as well.

There is a test specification with HOCON settings that you can check configuration against.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.7.x/web/play-filters-helpers/src/test/scala/play/filters/csp/CSPFilterSpec.scala#L69

Answer (score 0):

1. I can confirm the CSP with a nonce feature works, including this header which shows as X-Content-Security-Policy-Nonce when the CSPFilter is enabled and `play.filters.csp.nonce.enabled` is true and `play.filters.csp.nonce.header` is true. Don't forget to restart sbt after the config changes here.
2. When you inspect the html with the Firefox DOM inspector, part of the developer tools, the nonces show as empty strings. Have you tried using Right Click > View Source to see if the nonce is in the unprocessed raw html?
3. Everything seems to be whitelisted by the browser until you specify the nonce in the CSP, which can be done like this: `play.filters.csp.directives.script-src =  ${play.filters.csp.nonce.pattern} "'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"` and the `play.filters.csp.nonce.pattern` is `%CSP_NONCE_PATTERN%`.